# Java can't find ANTLR symbols ParserRuleContext and RContext

Tags: java, antlr4

I am trying out a project using ANTLR4 and I'm following this [tutorial](https://theendian.com/blog/antlr-4-lexer-parser-and-listener-with-example-grammar/) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555825/antlr4-is-there-a-simple-example-of-using-the-parsetree-walker).

The following is my Drink.java file

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import static org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromFileName;

public class Drink {

public static void main (String [] args) {
            CharStream cs = fromFileName("test.txt");  //load the file

            DrinkLexer lexer = new DrinkLexer(cs);  //instantiate a lexer
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); //scan stream for tokens
            DrinkParser parser = new DrinkParser(tokens);  //parse the tokens

            ParseTree tree = parser.drinkSentence(); // parse the content and get the tree
            DrinkWalker listener = new DrinkWalker();

            ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
            walker.walk(listener,tree);
    }
}
```

and the following is my DrinkWalker.java file

```
public class DrinkWalker extends DrinkBaseListener {
    @Override public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) {  
        System.out.println("rule entered: " + ctx.getText());//code that executes per rule
    }
    public void enterR(DrinkParser.RContext ctx ) {
            System.out.println( "Entering R : " + ctx.ID().getText() );
    }

    public void exitR(DrinkParser.RContext ctx ) {
            System.out.println( "Exiting R" );
    }
}
```

I compiled them manually, and I get the following errors:

```
Override public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
                                         ^
symbol:   class ParserRuleContext
location: class DrinkWalker

DrinkWalker.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    public void enterR(DrinkParser.RContext ctx ) {
                                  ^
symbol:   class RContext
location: class DrinkParser
DrinkWalker.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    public void exitR(DrinkParser.RContext ctx ) {
                                 ^
symbol:   class RContext
location: class DrinkParser
```

What are the RContext and ParserRuleContext functions referred above?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The previous referenced question was regarding Java in general. This question is about ANTLR.

Comment: These particular errors are happening because you need to add the antlr JAR file to your classpath. The example on the homepage of http://www.antlr.org/ shows one example. You'll have to adjust the path based on where yours is installed.